# OpenCV remove/cover specific contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a video that I want to remove some specific contours on, I capture the video and then draw all the contours;

```
//Prepare the image for findContours
cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(frame, frame, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

//Find the contours. Use the contourOutput Mat so the original image doesn't get overwritten
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat contourOutput = frame.clone();
cv::findContours( contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

//Draw the contours
cv::Mat contourImage(frame.size(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
cv::Scalar colors[3];
colors[0] = cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0);
colors[1] = cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0);
colors[2] = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255);
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
    cv::drawContours(contourImage, contours, idx, colors[idx % 3]);
}
```

The result looks like this:

[Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgho1.png)

So what I want to do now is to remove or cover objects like the trees and the tall house, basically contours that have a more complex shape than a road sign etc.

A desired result would look like this:

[Removed/covered contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0NPt.png)

It doesn't have to be exactly like on the picture as long as I can get something I can play with.

Comment: Inspect the contours one by one rather than drawing them all together into one picture. Figure out a way how to categorize them into the two types -- ones you want to retain and the ones you want to cover. Once you can make that decision figure out a way how to remove them - e.g. getting the contour bounding box and filling that with black in the image.

Comment: Your approach won't be particularly robust... But you can start playing around with contours dimensions (e.g. width, height, aspect ratio of its bounding box), length (from cv::arcLength), etc...

Comment: @DanMašek This is what I want to do, I have been searching for how to do this but could not find any easy solution that describes how to handle contours.

Comment: @C.JBlue IIRC contour is just a vector of points that basically define a polygon. Have a look through the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) -- there are a number of functions there to work with the contours.